# Saving PNG picture from SQL Server as BMP/JPG

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, vb6, adodb

I have a PNG picture in my SQL Server, I'm successfully getting the image and saving it to file.

```
rs.Open "Select pic from Table", connObj, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
    If Not IsNull(rs.Fields("pic").Value) Then
        Set mstream = New ADODB.Stream
        mstream.Type = adTypeBinary
        mstream.Open
        mstream.Write rs.Fields("pic").Value
        mstream.SaveToFile App.Path & "\MyPhoto.jpg", adSaveCreateOverWrite
    End If
End If
rs.Close
```

As you can see I already have my extension as .jpg but I don't think it matters, when I use the image in my vb6 application using `LoadPicture()` I get an `Invalid Picture` error. If I open the image and re-save it as jpg or bmp, `LoadPicture()` works.

So how can I save the picture properly as bmp/jpg?

Comment: Are you asking how to convert from PNG format to JPG format?

Answer (score 2):

You might find these two functions useful

```
Private Function LoadPictureFromBlob(baData() As Byte) As StdPicture
    With CreateObject("WIA.Vector")
        .BinaryData = baData
        Set LoadPictureFromBlob = .Picture
    End With
End Function

Private Sub SavePictureToJpg(oPic As StdPicture, sFile As String, Optional ByVal Quality = 80)
    Const wiaFormatJPEG As String = "{B96B3CAE-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}"
    Dim oImg            As Object

    SavePicture oPic, sFile
    Set oImg = CreateObject("WIA.ImageFile")
    oImg.LoadFile sFile
    With CreateObject("WIA.ImageProcess")
        .Filters.Add .FilterInfos("Convert").FilterID
        .Filters.Item(1).Properties("FormatID").Value = wiaFormatJPEG
        .Filters.Item(1).Properties("Quality").Value = Quality
        Set oImg = .Apply(oImg)
    End With
    On Error Resume Next
    Kill sFile
    On Error GoTo 0
    oImg.SaveFile sFile
End Sub
```

Just use `Set oPic = LoadPictureFromBlob(rs.Fields("pic").Value)` to read the `.png` and then either use built-in `SavePicture oPic, App.Path & "\MyPhoto.bmp"` to save to `.bmp` or `SavePictureToJpg oPic, App.Path & "\MyPhoto.jpg"` for `.jpg` and decide on the optional quality parameter.